# Are these queries the same? If not how to make more simple query

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Beginners question here, are these two queries the same? For some reason they give different count of rows.

**=> count of row ~2154**

```
SELECT * 
FROM kliendi_aadress 
WHERE maakond ~'\s\s' 
   OR linn ~'\s\s' 
   OR asula ~'\s\s' 
   OR tanav ~'\s\s' 
   OR maja ~'\s\s' 
   OR korter ~'\s\s' 
   OR postikood ~'\s\s'
```

**=> count of rows ~1923**

```
SELECT * 
FROM kliendi_aadress 
WHERE maakond || linn || asula || tanav || maja || korter || postikood ~'\s\s'
```

If not how to make first query more simple and faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries may return different results, because a simple columns concatenation may add extra two-spaces substrings. You can try the concatenation with separator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM kliendi_aadress 
WHERE concat_ws(',', maakond, linn, asula, tanav, maja, korter, postikood) ~ '\s\s'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Same result as first query.

Answer (score 1):

It returns something different because you have "Tanav" in the next query written twice?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo when editing. correct one was like in top.